# MongoDB: Add date comparison to arrayFilters

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Objects of my collection have a field, that is an array of objects with one of the field being a string date

```
{
    citizens: [{
      name: 'John'
      birthday: '1993/07/13'
    }, 
    {
      name: 'Sarah'
      birthday: '1996/07/13'
    },
    {
      name: 'Natalia',
      birthday: '2015/07/13'
    }]
}
{
    citizens: [{
      name: 'Leo'
      birthday: '1994/02/08'
    }, 
    {
      name: 'Paul'
      birthday: '1934/09/13'
    },
    {
      name: 'Rego',
      birthday: '2019/01/29'
    }]
}
```

I want to set to all the users older than 18 status 'adult'
Here is what I try to do:

```
  users.updateMany({}, {
    $set: { 'citizens.$[elem].status': 'adult' },
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { 'elem.status': { $exists: false } },
      { $lt: [{ $toDate: 'elem.$birthday' }, 18yearsaAgoDate] }, <-- 18years don't mean much here, I actually use $$NOW
    ],
    multi: true,
  });
```

But I get '**unknown top level operator: $lt**' error when run this. How do I supposed to use $lt in arrayFilter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would have worked like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cKPX4qSAAdY) if your date was already in the right format. Since you need to format it, I think you should use an aggregation pipeline with a `$merge` stage

Comment: Yep, date format complicates everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an update using the `arrayFilters` syntax.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { }, 
  {
      $set: { "citizens.$[elem].status": "adult" }
  },
  {
      arrayFilters: [ { "elem.status": { $exists: false } , "elem.birthday": { $lt: "2004/07/27" }  } ]
  }
)
```

Note the date value `"2004/07/27"` is the day 18 years ago (very close approximate value). And using *string* values in date comparison requires that the value is formatted in "YYYY/mm/dd".

Comment: Wow, that sounds great. I was not sure if lt for string date works, will try, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it in a simple update using the aggregation pipelined updates:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      citizens: {
        $map: {
          input: "$citizens",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                status: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $gt: [
                        {
                          $dateDiff: {
                            startDate: {
                              $toDate: "$$this.birthday"
                            },
                            endDate: "$$NOW",
                            unit: "year"
                          }
                        },
                        18
                      ]
                    },
                    "adult",
                    "$$REMOVE"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VU4qyRODruy)

I've used some version 5+ operators like `$dateDiff` as it makes the code cleaner, but you could still achieve the same results without them using `$subtract` and a constant for 18 years, like so:

```
{
    $lt: [
        {
            $toDate: "$$this.birthday"
        },
        {
            $subtract: [
                "$$NOW",
                567648000000// 18 years in miliseconds

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/89sFg73Tdzr)

Comment: This answer is very similar to mine, but it is better, as the aggregation pipeline is inside the update. I vote for this one.

Comment: Thanks! In real case I need just to check if date is in the past, so I replaced substract block with just $$NOW. That worked for update(). but fails for updateMany(): 'MongoError: the update operation document must contain atomic operators'

Comment: updateMany behaves weirdly, update with {multi: true} works. not perfect but does what it does! Using just update is deprecated though, so will look for a way to use updateMany

Comment: This syntax works for me on Mongo V5.2 using `updateMany`, can you share exactly the syntax you're using?

Comment: If I use updateMany instead of update for exactly same code (with [{$set: ...}])it gives MongoError: the update operation document must contain atomic operators

Comment: If I remove [] and use {$set: ...} - it literally replaces citizens: [ name: '', bithday: ''] with citizens: {$map: ...} (so it copypastes code after 'citizens:')

Answer (score 1):

It would have worked like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cKPX4qSAAdY) if your date was already in the right format. Since you need to format it, I think you should use an aggregation pipeline with a $merge stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      citizens: {
        $map: {
          input: "$citizens",
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              {status: {
                  $cond: [
                    {$lt: [{$toDate: "$$this.birthday"}, 18yearsaAgoDate]},
                    "adult",
                    "$$REMOVE"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $merge : { into : "collection" } }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NtbLUFruqvH)

Comment: Should I use update() after aggregate?

Comment: No. The `$merge` stage will update your collection